# Time-based workflows and triggered transactions

Tags: apex, workflow, time-dependent-workflow, transaction

Say that there is a time based workflow on creation which updates something after 1 day. Two records are created via two different API calls (say we exposed a REST service), these two different calls may be very close in time. They trigger two separate transactions but what happens when the time-based workflow expires? Is there any circumstance in which we would have 1 transaction with 2 records?

Comment: it's the opposite scenario form the suggested question, I understand it's very similar:) it's the other way around, there I was asking if I insert 10 in 1 transaction what will happen, here I am asking if I insert 10 in 10 different transactions, is there any chance I'll have less than 10 transactions form the timed workflow?

Comment: Yes, I realize they're not "exactly" the same, but the end result is. WFR only runs once every 15 minutes, so if multiple records fall in the same window, they will be one transaction, unless they exceed the hourly limit, in which case they may be split in to multiple transactions.